# Django rest framework: Reject upload before parser

Tags: django, http, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I have an upload API for my Django app specified with Django REST framework.

```py
from rest_framework import views

class MyUploadView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (
        CanUploadFilePermission,
    )
    parser_classes = (parsers.FileUploadParser,)
```

I noticed that the permissions are only checked after the file has already been uploaded/processed by the `FileUploadParser`.

Unfortunately, I could not find any information in the Django REST framework of the execution stack for API calls. So I don't even know which parts (parser, permission, authentication etc) are executed in which order.

Is it possible to reject a file upload before `FileUploadParser` even read the entire file into buffer?
My goal is also to limit the file upload size depending on the user permissions and rejecting the request if the HTTP `Content-Length` header is larger than what is allowed for a certain user before the server even starts to write it into its buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `APIView` class. The requests start in the `dispatch` method and from there you can see the call stack. As the saying goes, the code is the best documentation. I have found this to be particularly true for DRF especially if you want understand the low-level details.

Now, if you check the `restframework.requests.Request` class, you will see that the request data and files are loaded lazily only when `request.FILES` or `request.data` is accessed. So what you need to do is to make sure, none of those properties are accessed before the permission is checked.

From what I see in the DRF views and viewsets, those properties are not accessed until the permission is checked so it seems what you want is already implemented by default. You can add a custom permission to `content-type` header and authorize user upload as you mentioned.

Comment: This has been extremely helpful, thanks! Also the general advise how to go about with Django rest framework. I have been really frustrated with the documentation, and using the code as documentation might be the best thing to do. I just checked the Request class and you are right, seems to be loaded lazily.
I will try out if accessing the header fields as part of the permissions will help